# PHP Codeigniter pagination missing First and Last

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter setup for pagination, which is working properly except that it does not show the First and Last options. It does show previous and next.

[image: My Current Pagination]

I have setup this config as follows:

```
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/main";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->Pages_model->user_count();
$config["per_page"] = 15;
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$num_pages = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = round($num_pages);
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>'; 
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$seg = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
$data['loaded'] = $this->Content_model->loadVisitors($config["per_page"], $seg);
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
```

What am I missing to have a First and Last feature? I can't seem to find anything in [the docs.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

EDIT: also just to mention, my view is as follows:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?php echo $links; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the page, this is what it shows:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="index.php/main" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="prev">&lt;</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php/main" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="start">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php/main/30" data-ci-pagination-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php/main/45" data-ci-pagination-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php/main/60" data-ci-pagination-page="5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php/main/30" data-ci-pagination-page="3" rel="next">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>       
</div>
```

Comment: try this `$config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;'.'First'; `

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anyting

Comment: just for try remove `&lt;`  and write there `First`. Its just for test and please see my updated comment @Mitch

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: check by inspect element and look what are come there. Its may be possible to some css effect so. @Mitch

Comment: I updated my question to include a copy of the inspected element. As you can see the first and last don't show up.

Comment: Do you have more than 5 pages? try $config["per_page"] = 5;. if all possible pages are being displayed then CI will hide first and last links.

Comment: I think it's not necessary to use $config["num_links"] = round($num_pages)... Remove from configuration.

Comment: I did have more than 5 pages, it was not diplaying all 5 pages. Arjun was correct as I posted in an answer, I removed that configuration and it worked. This was intended to automatically have more links shown when there was a large amount of pages, but in my case it is unnecessary. I'm not sure why it stopped it from working though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config['first_link'] = 'First'; 
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
```

Comment: I tried this, however it still did not show First and Last

Comment: if you change any other parameters like $config["per_page"] will it affect the display ?

Comment: I tried changing other parameters but it has no effect. Even having as little as 5 per page resulting in 30+ pages there is no first and last.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue right now; I think if you have only a few pages & there are already numbered links to those pages, the first or last will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem must be in core file, change the following things min your
>   core file and try it.
>   system/libraries/pagination.php

line 231 – first link

```
$output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
```

> **TO**

```
$output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.$this->suffix.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
```

line 285 – 1 link

```
$output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
```

> **TO**

```
$output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.$this->suffix.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
```

> add $this->suffix variable after $this->first_url value i think you
>   must not ‘hack’ the $this->first_url value to concat with
>   $this->suffix,  it will ruined the ‘if’ decision in line above
>   i hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> To show text in first and last link you should place string in quotes.

```
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
```

> You can get proper documentation here
>   https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: It's not that there is no text, The first and last links simply do not exist when viewed. The < and > you are seeing in the picture are the previous/next links. I'm not sure why there is no First/Last. I have read the documentation, and cannot find an answer. I have tried with text instead of << and >> like I have coded but this does not work as I have mentioned to other answers.

Comment: did you check your uri segment ? is it working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this code was causing it not to show First and Last

```
$num_pages = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = round($num_pages);
```

Removing this code it works. Fortunately, I did not necessarily need this, however if anyone knows why this stopped it from working, I would appreciate a response to that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include last and first tags and their opening and closing tags like this...

for first tag.....

```
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>'
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

for last tag.....`

```
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';`
```